# min(column) with nulls?

Tags: oracle

I am new to databases, but I hope you can help me to understand something.

Take part of this query:

> select min(date) as date...

Assume that some of the dates are null. What effect would it have? Would the query break?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`MIN` will return the smallest non-NULL value.  The query won't throw an error, it will simply ignore the NULL values

```
SQL> with x as (
  2    select null dt from dual union all
  3    select sysdate from dual
  4  )
  5  select min(dt)
  6    from x;

MIN(DT)
---------
21-OCT-11
```

Answer (score 7):

> Assume that some of the dates are null

For completeness, I'm also assuming there may be zero rows

I'm using this test data:

```
create table t as
select to_date('20110101', 'YYYYMMDD')+level-1 as d from dual connect by level<=5
union all select null from dual;

select * from t;
D                         
------------------------- 
01-JAN-11 00.00.00        
02-JAN-11 00.00.00        
03-JAN-11 00.00.00        
04-JAN-11 00.00.00        
05-JAN-11 00.00.00        
(null)
```

and considering the following cases:

1. some rows but no `null` values:

   ```
   select min(d) from t where d is not null;
   MIN(D)                    
   ------------------------- 
   01-JAN-11 00.00.00
   ```
2. some rows and both `null` and non-`null` values:

   ```
   select min(d) from t;
   MIN(D)                    
   ------------------------- 
   01-JAN-11 00.00.00
   ```
3. some rows and all values are `null`:

   ```
   select min(d) from t where d is null;
   MIN(D)                    
   ------------------------- 
   (null)
   ```
4. no rows:

   ```
   select min(d) from t where 1=2;
   MIN(D)                    
   ------------------------- 
   (null)
   ```
5. an interesting edge case with `group by` that returns no rows:

   ```
   select min(d) from t where 1=2 group by 1;
   MIN(D)                    
   -------------------------
   ```

---

<sub>*aside: I've haven't used `date` as an alias because Oracle complains (not unreasonably IMO)*:</sub>

```
select to_date('20110101', 'YYYYMMDD') as date from dual;
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```